# pgfplots: plot from csv file starting at a specified row

Tags: pgfplots

I do have a large csv file which contains more data than that what I actually want to plot. E.g. I have data starting from x=0, but I want to plot it starting from x=2, but still let the axis start at xmin=0. Is it possible to specify a 'starting row' e.g. in the table command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
x,       y
1,       0.000004824
2,       0.000004687
3,       0.000009425
4,       0.000004794
5,       0.000004565
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot table [col sep=comma] {mydata.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to blindly drop the rows? If you know the coordinate range you want to keep, there are the `xmin` (`xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`) and `restrict x to domain` (`restrict y to domain`) keys documented in the manual of pgfplots.

Comment: @mvkorpel thanks for the hint, this works! On the same page in the manual I found the `skip coords between index` command which does something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the methods mentioned in the comments, this solution proposes `discard if smaller/.style` mechanism that takes two arguments: #1=x and #2=starting row. The demonstration below is for row 2 by putting `discard if smaller={x}{2}` in the `addplot` options

```
discard if smaller/.style n args={2}{x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
                \ifnum\tempa<\tempb
                    \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
                \else
                \fi
        }
    }
    }
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
x,       y
1,       0.000004824
2,       0.000004687
3,       0.000009425
4,       0.000004794
5,       0.000004565
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

 \pgfplotsset{
    discard if smaller/.style n args={2}{
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
                \ifnum\tempa<\tempb
                    \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
                \else
                \fi
        }
    }
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0]
\addplot +[discard if smaller={x}{2}] table[only marks,x=x,y=y, col sep=comma]{mydata.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```