# PGFPLOTS limit plotting from file by non-plotted coulmn

Tags: pgfplots, filter

I have data, that contains three columns: time, x, y. Now, I want to plot the data in the x-y plane like this:

```
\addplot[] table[x expr={\thisrowno{1}}, y expr={\thisrowno{2}}] {test.csv};
```

But furthermore, I only want to plot the data where the time fulfils certain conditions, e.g. only plot the first 300ns.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to scrape together the answer, so I wanted to share it here. This can be achieved by using

```
\addplot[x filter/.expression={\thisrowno{0} <= 300e-9 ? nan : x}] table[x expr={\thisrowno{1}}, y expr={\thisrowno{2}}] test.csv};
```

(using an example from the [coordfiltering lib](https://github.com/live-clones/pgfplots/blob/master/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.reference.coordfiltering.tex))

Note how returning the `nan` for the x discards the whole datapoint.

More along the lines of this post [pgfplots: plot from csv file starting at a specified row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186511/pgfplots-plot-from-csv-file-starting-at-a-specified-row) (which did not work at all for me) one can also write it as

```
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if larger/.style n args={2}{
        x filter/.expression={
            \thisrowno{#1} < #2 ? nan : x
        }
    },
    discard if smaller/.style n args={2}{
        x filter/.expression={
            \thisrowno{#1} > #2 ? nan : x
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
\addplot[discard if larger={0}{300e-9}] table[x expr={\thisrowno{1}}, y expr={\thisrowno{2}}] test.csv};
```